# Существует ли такое слово: куала-лумпурец (или куалалумпурец)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, названия

куала-лумпурец (или куалалумпурец)

Comment: Вот она, "высшая математика" тонкостей нашего языка! Никто не может подсказать...

Answer (score 2):

Позвольте изменить вопрос. Как назвать жителя города Куала-Лумпур? Первое — поискать название в словарях. Следует обращаться к специальным словарям-справочникам. Но в доступных мне словарях я ответа не нашел, поэтому предлагаю построить это слово самостоятельно.

Вообще-то говоря, в русском языке нет строгих правил формирования названий жителей стран и городов. Используются разные словообразовательные модели с помощью суффиксов -ец, -ениц, -овец, -анин, -янин, -ич (указаны суффиксы для жителей единственного числа мужского рода). Большое число новых названий жителей стран и городов образовано с помощью суффикса -ец, вот им и воспользуемся. Тем более что суффикс -ец обычно добавляют к иностранным названиям мужского рода (Таллин — таллинец).

В моих рассуждениях мне помог сайт http://residentname.ru/

Остается решить, писать слитно или через дефис. Вот правило:

**Существительные, образованные от пишущихся через дефис собственных имен, пишутся слитно.**

> [Вопрос № 201711](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=201711)
>   Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли писать слитно "пуэрториканец" и почему. А то "нутром чую", что правильно, а обосновать не могу...
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Чуете правильно :) Существительные, образованные от пишущихся через дефис собственных имен, пишутся слитно: *пуэрториканец, лосанджелесец, санктпетербуржец*.

Итак, ответ: **куалалумпурец**.